# How to deploy a firebase app without authentication?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a firebase app/game which does not require any authentication. My plan is that anyone should be able to open the website or the mobile app and start playing directly. I don't need to record any user ids.
Firebase keeps emailing me

> We've detected the following issue(s) with your security rules: any
> user can read your entire database any user can write to your entire
> database
>
> Because your project does not have strong security rules, anyone can
> access your entire database. Attackers can steal, modify, or delete
> your data, and they can drive up your bill.

My concern is, are there any work around for this?
Is it not normal to have an app without authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You should anyway activate [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth?authuser=0) which would allow to define basic security rules and limit CRUD access to data based on user id.

This is the way.

Comment: This wouldn't be such a good idea though, right?

Comment: I don't have enough information about the project to be so sure of that. For sure, it is a challenge to protect user data and avoid potential attackers to use the database for unplanned and potentially dangerous usages. Depending on project, since user is anonymous, data may be store in the browser or app local storage...

Answer (score 0):

> Is it not normal to have an app without authentication?

It is not normal to skip use of authentication for apps released to the public.  The email is trying to warn that bad things can happen if you do this, and those bad things will be easy to execute for an attacker.

If you do actually intend to publish something publicly writable, at least write your rules to constrain the public write access to a specific collection, and be clear in your rules exactly what kinds of writes are allowed.  Don't leave the entire database open, else it's extremely easy for someone to cause you significant problems.

It's up to you to decide if you want public write access, but you need to be aware of the risk. If something happens and an attacker runs up a bill, you will be on the hook for any costs involved.

Comment: The app is a quiz app. Anyone can open the website, create a quiz, share the link with his friends and they can open the link and start playing directly. I just wanted fast user experience. I don't want to record anything. Just play and leave. No users, No history. How can I put rules in this case?

Comment: The security of your app is up to you.  If you can't define the requirements for reading and writing, then you can't write rules.